# How do I Assign a random number to a variable?

Tags: python, random

Before I say anything else, I would like to mention that I am almost completely new to coding,  and only have a very rudimentary understanding of python.

Now that that's out of the way, my problem is that I am (attempting) to code a text adventure game, along the lines of D&D. I'm stuck at an early stage- namely, how to assign a random integer between 1 and 18 to a variable.

I've seen some ways of doing this, but the value of the variable changes each time it's called up. This can't happen. The reason for this is because I want the stats (Strength, Wisdom, Intelligence, Dexterity, Charisma, and Constitution) to be a randomly generated but fixed number, that can be called upon and have it the same each time.

I've tried mucking around with things like `Str = random.randomint(1,18)`, using the random module.

The closest I've come is using the lambda function, so that when I call up the variable it generates a random number which is different each time. None of these have rally worked, and I would really like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you are simulating 3 rolls of 6 side dices, shouldn't be a random between 3 and 18?

Comment: @MarceloAssis: no, it should be 3 random numbers between 1 and 6 added together (although OP doesn't mention actually using 3d6).

Comment: @Wooble And the results would be different, when using 3 randoms?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "call upon" a number?

Comment: When you're beginning coding, don't start using a Lambda too early. Unless your interested in functional programming, that is.

Comment: @MarceloAssis Results would be different if you use standard random generator with equal distribution. A result of 3 is actually much less probable as e.g. 10.

Answer (score 8):

I see you are very close with what you have:

`Str = random.randomint(1,18)` should be `Str = random.randint(1,18)`

This is the line which assigns the random int to the variable `Str`, and when you ask for `Str` you should get the same number each time.

If you keep calling `Str = random.randint(1,18)` it will change `Str` each time. so only do it once.

If you know or understand about `classes` you should use them to contain your characters/items/spells/adventures/monsters etc. which can have properties and attributes and inventories etc etc, much like in the game itself, you group all the things under different types.

Note: You mention you used lambda, that might mean that you have assigned `Str` to a function which returns a random variable each time, meaning each time you asked for `Str` you would actually be asking for the function to return a random number.

Comment: It's `random.randint`, `random.randomint` doesn't exist :)

Comment: +1 for understanding what the OP really wants :)

Comment: @mgilson thanks, i copied OPS code without looking too closely.

Comment: @RoxDorentus haha, yeah, it took me a while to realize where he probably was going wrong.

Comment: Many thanks. One question though- What exactly is the difference between what I have and your correction? 
"Str = random.randomint(1,18) should be Str = random.randint(1,18)"
Maybe it's just me but both of those look the same to me. Apart from that, it's very helpful indeed.

Comment: @user1987349 well, they may 'look' the same, but similarity does not mean identical. for instance, in this case there is a function called `randint` under the `random` module, but there is not a function called `randomint` under the `random` module.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to coding.

I've been a web developer for a while and I've also recently started to sink my teeth into better things than php (in my opinion).  I would also use:

```
Str = random.randomint(1,18)
```

Are you using an IDE? I found they're great when you're first learning a new language due to the code completion.  It really helps you get to know your way around the language faster, due to not having to go to various websites to look up syntax.  Good luck! Text based adventure games are a great way to start learning!